# How to find the value $A(y,z) , B(x, z) ?$

Tags: calculus

I have  some  doubts  in *Tom M. APOSTOL Calculas*  Volume $2$ books

My doubts  is given below  in red line 
[image]

Im not getting this  line  and How  to derive  the value of A$(y,z)$ , B$(x,z)$ and C$(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$\varphi(x,y,z)=x^2yz+xz^2-2xy^2+x+A(y,z)\\
\varphi(x,y,z)=x^2yz-2xy^2+B(x,z)\\
\varphi(x,y,z)=x^2yz+xz^2-2z+C(x,y)\\$

Now, for example, our $3$rd equation clearly shows that the potential function $\varphi$ must have some function $C(x,y)$, and when we check our $1$st and $2$nd equations., i.e. what parts in them contains some dependence about $x$ and $y$, it is obvious that $C(x,y)$ is having form of: $-2xy^2 +x$.

Similarly, our $2$nd equation clearly shows that the potential function $\varphi$ must have some function $B(x,z)$, and when we check our $1$st and $3$rd equations., i.e. what parts in them contains some dependence about $x$ and $z$, it is obvious that $B(x,z)$ is having form of: $xz^2 +x - 2z$.

Finally, we can conclude the form of $A(y,z)$ as $-2z$.